# Error Using rclpy module on a non ROS2 machine

Tags: ros, ros2, dds, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to communicate between a ROS2 machine(Linux VM) and a non ROS machine(Host Windows).  I have configured the network connections. When I install ROS on the windows machine as well, and run a demo talker on Windows and a listener on Linux, they communicate. Now when I try to run the demo talker using rclpy, it doesnt.

In windows, from the terminal, I run the `demo_nodes_py talker.py` and I get the error : `Traceback (most recent call last): File "listener.py", line 17, in <module> import rclpy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy'`

Any idea how to use the rclpy API ? What am I doing wrong here ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293723/error-using-rclpy-module-on-a-non-ros2-machine/) by [vishal_rawat](https://answers.ros.org/users/35786/vishal_rawat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-10**:\

> When I install ROS on the windows machine as well

I don't understand: how is something a "non-ROS machine" if you install ROS2 on it?

**Comment by [vishal_rawat](https://answers.ros.org/users/35786/vishal_rawat/) on 2018-06-11**:
Just to check if the communication works on 2 different ROS2 machines, i installed ROS2 also on Windows...so that works...but now I dont need to use ROS2 rather only its API (rclpy) @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-12**:
Not using ROS2 but only its API does not make sense. If you use `rclpy`, you are using ROS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you going through all the steps to enable ROS2 in your command shell before trying to run the `rclpy` demo? You especially must run `call C:\dev\ros2\local_setup.bat` first.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0